# C++ makefile that compiles both .o and .exe

Tags: c++, makefile

My professor didn't give us any information and I cant seem to find a solution with resources online.

We need to create a makefile for a .cpp file. It should compile a .o file, and an executable file. Also a command clean that removes both of these files. This is what I currently have, any help?

```
List: List.cpp
    g++ List.cpp -o List

List.o: List.cpp
    g++ List.cpp -c -o List.o

clean:
    rm List
    rm List.o
```

Comment: This is the basic example shown at the beginning of every `make` tutorial or reverence -- please search for one, if you have problems **after** you have researched an issue, then post the question here after reading the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page and the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: At the very least you should explain what the problem is you're trying to solve.  "Any help?" is not a problem description.  What is it about this makefile that doesn't do what you want?  What does it do (what command do you type?  What output do you get?)  Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing more work than you need to there.

Usually the *executable* file is generated from the `.o` file.

**1)** *Compile* the `.cpp` file to make an `.o` file.

**2)** *Link* the `.o` file to make an *executable* file.

```
# List.o depends on List.cpp
# If List.cpp changes, recompile List.o
List.o: List.cpp
    g++ -c -o List.o List.cpp

# List depends on List.o
# If List.o changes, relink List
List: List.o
    g++ -o List List.o

clean:
    rm List
    rm List.o
```

Comment: You should also declare `clean` as `phony` .